# How do I subscribe to pages that don't support RSS?

Tags: rss

Back before RSS became so common, I there was a site that watched web pages for me and sent me the text that changed each day-- that site stopped working and I don't remember the name anymore.

There are still pages on the web without RSS feeds, what need web watchers (with web clients or otherwise) are there for me to turn to?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Webapp that watches a URL and notifies of any changes](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/3822/webapp-that-watches-a-url-and-notifies-of-any-changes)

Comment: sorry, didn't see the other one.  It certainly has ended up with duplicate answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Google Reader (www.google.com/reader) has some support for sites without RSS. See their blog post titled, "[Follow changes to any website](http://googlereader.blogspot.com/2010/01/follow-changes-to-any-website.html)" for more details.

Comment: This looks even more promising than page differences, since it outputs RSS.

Comment: Unfortunately they are discontinuing this awesome feature on Sept 30th: http://googlereader.blogspot.com/2010/09/turning-off-track-changes-feature.html

Answer (score 3):

It might be worth checking this extension out if you use Firefox: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4337/

> This extension adds a small Delta icon to your browser status bar. When you click onto it, **it highlights all changed text contents of the current page** (since the last time you clicked onto it). Clicking again cycles through the changes. Rightclick onto the icon allows you to add scan or ignore regions and manage pages known to SiteDelta.
>   Furthermore SiteDelta can regularly check its known pages for changes and inform you whenever one of them was updated.